# Datagridview comboboxes only in some rows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

In my winforms application, I have a `DataGridView` where one row uses the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn control so that it contains comboboxes for this column.

Is it possible to programatically replace some of the comboboxes in that column with something else? (for example a label saying "n/a"). I only want a combobox in certain rows.

Comment: Though this type of functionality is possible (placing a label in some rows and not in others), the performance ramifications are high. Would a solution that simply leveraged an additional item added to the list items who's display value was `N/A` be acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` property instead of `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` property. Something like below:

```
for(int intCount=0;intCount<dgv.Rows.Count;intCount++)
{
   if(intCount % 2 == 0)  //Your own condition here
   {
      DataGridViewComboBoxCell cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
      //cmb.Value   // assign values in the combobox
      dgv[0,intCount] = cmb;
   }
   else
   {
      DataGridViewTextBoxCell txt = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
      txt.Value = "n/a";
      dgv[0,intCount] = txt;
   }
}
```

In the above example, I am assigning the Individual cell properties in the first column.